# How to overwrite global RootParamList in react-navigation v6

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

In the upgrade guide to react-navigation v6:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/#ability-to-specify-a-type-for-root-navigator-when-using-typescript

it states that you can use

```js
declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
  }
}
```

somewhere in your code to set the RootParamList globally for all hooks etc.

However, when I try to include the snippet and set my param list all I get is

```
Duplicate identifier 'RootParamList'.ts(2300)
types.d.ts(5, 19): 'RootParamList' was also declared here
```

Obviously, the type is already declared and I am trying to overwrite it but this does not seem to be possible.

Any ideas how to overwrite without resulting in a type error?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it was caused because I was not using the exact same snippet as suggested. I use `eslint` and it would state that "an interface declaring no members is equivalent to its supertype", and in my case, `vim` would automatically turn this:

```
declare global {
 namespace ReactNavigation {
   interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
 }
}
```

Into this:

```
declare global {
 namespace ReactNavigation {
   type RootParamList = RootStackParamList;
 }
}
```

The problem is that `react-navigation` [declares RootParamList using an interface](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/4cc322e/packages/core/src/types.tsx#L16). In this case, my `RootParamList` was really a declaration.

To solve the problem, I just ensure to use an interface and disabled the `@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface` rule:

```
declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!